# H2O: Time varying covariates in Cox PH model?

Tags: h2o

H2O [supports](http://docs.0xdata.com/datascience/coxph.html) the [Cox proportional hazards model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proportional_hazards_model). But the notation on the first link does not make it clear whether it supports [time varying covariates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proportional_hazards_model#Time-varying_predictors_and_coefficients). Does it?

Comment: @floor lolwut? tumblr is ----> way.

Answer (score 0):

If Cox models are supported, then time-varying covariates are supported. The key is ensuring the data are formatted in the proper way. Each event change is a censoring event, then the participant is re-entered into the study at the change time with the new covariates. There is one line per time-varying event and then a final censoring or death event. If need be, the dataset must be transformed from wide to long which is easily done in base R or virtually any statistical programming language.